Passing argument value to npm script via CLI
I have a typescript project. In package.json, I have npm script:
"test:add": "cross-env some-static-var=value npm run some-command"

Now I want to pass a variable value when I run the script in CLI. I just need to pass a value, it will be ok if no var name is passed in CLI. I mean to run the script like this:
npm run test:add --additionalValue

Please help, I do not know how to pass a value from CLI. Please also let me know how can I access the value. I tried running command with "-- --" process.env, process.argv and process.arg0 does not seems to contain additionalValue.

Can you share how you used process.argv and what your script looks like in package.json?

I think you're close, here's a simple implementation of that operation.
package.json has this script:
"scripts": {
    "helloWorld": "node hello-world.js"
  },

hello-world.js would look like this:
const arg = process.env.npm_config_hello || "";

console.log(arg);

And the npm command would be this:
npm run helloWorld --hello="Hello World!"

And this would output Hello World!
Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/cg2sg8

I do not need to create hello-world.js. I can directly use process.env.npm_config_hello in my .ts files. But thanks a lot for the idea. :)

I don't think @boocher is suggesting that you need to create a hello-world.js file.  He is showing you the pattern for passing variables with NPM commands.
This should be the accepted answer.
